# audio files does not play properly depending on timer in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am displaying countdown timer from 5 to 1 in label .When my countdown timer is displayed i am trying to play audio in background for particular label i.e if 5 is displayed audio sound of 5 should be played and  if 4 is displayed after 1 sec, audio sound of 4 should be played and so on.I have done the code but the problem is all the audio sounds of 5,4,3,2,1 are played at the same time.This is my code.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    countDown = 7;
    exitcountdown = 0;
    lblCountdown.hidden = YES;
    btnCancel.hidden = YES;
    lblCancel.hidden = YES;
    countDownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [countDownTimer fire];


}





-(void)updateTime:(NSTimer*)timerParam
{

    countDown--;
    if (countDown==5)
    {
        lblCountdown.hidden = NO;
        lblCountdown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",countDown];
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",countDown] ofType:@"mp3"]; 
                if ([player isPlaying])
        {
            [player stop];
        }
        player= [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
        player.delegate = self;
        [player stop];
        [player setCurrentTime:0.0];
        [player setVolume:100.0];
        [player play];
        lblCancel.hidden = NO;
        btnCancel.hidden = NO;
        lblWarning.hidden = YES;
        lblGps.hidden = YES;

        [countDownTimer fire];
    }
    else if (countDown==0)
    {
        [self sendRequest];
        countDownTimerexit = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(exitBackground:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [countDownTimerexit fire];
        NSString *phoneLinkString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", self.emergencyphonenumber];
        NSURL *phoneLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneLinkString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneLinkURL];

        [self clearCountDownTimer];
        btnCancel.hidden = YES;
        lblCancel.hidden = YES;

    }
    lblCountdown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",countDown];
}
```

lblCountdown is the label where the countDown is being printed as 5,4,3,2,1.
countDown is an int variable 
countDownTimer is NSTimer Variable

Answer (score 0):

What is happening in your code as i think is displaying text on the label is fast process than playing a sound. 5 is displayed and you requested for play sound before sound for 5 reach to end your counter becomes 4 and after that you stop the player and request for next file.

try to insert some delay between playing sound and showing next number.